# How to guess locale from this date Tue 8/26/2014 2:59 AM?

Tags: java

I have this date but do not know timezone/ country

Tue 8/26/2014 2:59 AM

Using code how I can best guess from which country/locale this date is ?

Give code example in java

Comment: I don't know if anyone had/would put an effort to create such library, the result is still going to be a guess which is just narrowed down a little bit.

Comment: but what if iso format? On iso format you cannot determine which locale is.

Comment: By asking for a tool, you are automatically asking your question to be closed. You should have asked "How can I find the date format for the following date". Then show some code.

Comment: As far as I can see, the format is so braindead that it must be `en_US`.

Comment: Agree with @Makoto.......NA uses this date format quite prevalently....The only thing I can think about is if it was in some form of class where a field is `localType`, you could assign the values to it. Other than that, not quite worth the effort I believe.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, No, there is no library for this.

First you'd need a list of all locales: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Then, for each Locale, format the current date accordingly:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Then compare the output with the format you have.

You might get more than one matches, through this method, since there are many countries that use the same masks for dates.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has nothing to do with computers or Java, but with a little understanding of how dates are formatted in other parts of the world.

Consider that European (and [most other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)) countries use dd/MM/yyyy.  This would mean that the date format would appear as Tue 26/8/2014 2:59 AM.  The format you're showing us is MM/dd/yyyy, which I've *only* ever noticed in the United States.

Then again, if that data is coming direct from an end user, you miss the case in which they may be lying to you - at that point, there's not much you can go off of.

There's no formal library for this - unless you feel up to brute forcing every locale that Oracle knows about.  It's a matter of understanding internationalization more than anything.